# Convincing Telephone Effect

Tags: effects, phone

I know this is probably been said, and I know there is a preset on the effects panel in Adobe Audition. Though using a preset feels like cheating and samples will sound the same. I want to know is there a way to make it a little more convincing? In the sample below there is mouth breathing, is this done during recording or can it be done after with distortion? and how?

around 41:40 or anywhere with call ins.

Answer (score 2):

some light phone handling added in along with the correct EQ and a speaker simulator will usually get you what you need.  Or a plugin like Speakerphone will let you get to a good place very quickly also.

Comment: Yes, Speakerphone is the gold standard for this, it will nail exactly that — and many other types of simulated spaces effects. It's incredibly versatile and fun, it has impulse responses for various types of telephones and a mic degrade option to further grit things up. If you find it too expensive, look into Plogue Chipcrusher and McDSP Futzbox.

Answer (score 1):

Put a high pass filter at 300 Hz, a low pass at 3300 Hz, and compress the heck out of it (compression will help with the breathing noises). You might want to add a little distortion to replicate the carbon microphones that at least used to be common in telephones. If you have a chance to record the audio, put the mic as close to the talent's mouth as a telephone mic would be to better replicate capture of breathing and mouth noises. And I would just use a cheap dynamic mic for it.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you for quick response.

Comment: Why these values 300Hz and 3300Hz ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Long ago the phone company (in North America at least) decided that it wanted to design for a 3 kHz bandwidth and wanted to get the most important frequencies for human speach. Most voices don't go below 300 Hz in general so they started there and went up 3 kHz to 3.3 kHz. One issue (in terms of phone calls) is that sibilants and fricatives have important information at 5 kHz and above, so on the phone it can be hard to tell an "f" from an "s". See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service

Comment: With replicating this sort of degraded sound quality, a bitcrusher is useful to bring the sample rate down to 8kHz, which, if I remember correctly, is the sample rate of a standard telephone signal. Without doing research, I'm not sure about the bit depth.

Comment: I think an ISDN B channel actually carries 8 kHz x 7 bit words for a total bandwidth of 56 kbps (the other 8 kbps are used for control data), hence the maximum modem speed. You could replicate that with a 7 kHz bit crusher if that is available, or 8 kHz if that's the closest available setting. Good idea!